# How can I get a list of values for a certain property

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'd like to have a list of values for a certain property of an object inside an `ArrayList`. Supposing I have a class like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private String b, a, r;
    //Constructor...
    //Getters...
}
```

Then I create an `ArrayList<Foo>`:

```
ArrayList<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>();
fooList.add(new Foo("How", "Hey", "Hey"));
fooList.add(new Foo("Can", "Hey", "Hey"));
fooList.add(new Foo("I", "Hey", "Hey"));
fooList.add(new Foo("Get", "Hey", "Hey"));
fooList.add(new Foo("Those?", "Hey", "Hey"));
```

In an `ArrayList<Foo>`, is it possible to get a List of a certain property of `Foo` without having to iterate over my `ArrayList` using a `for` loop? Maybe something simillar to [valueforkey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/valueForKey:) in Objective-c. This would make easier to print values using `TextUtils.join()` if I had  an `ArrayList<String>` containing `How`, `Can`, `I`, `Get`, and `Those`.

Comment: Do you have Guava or Java 8?

Comment: Which do you have? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java 8, you can stream, map and collect:

```
List<String> list = fooList.stream()
        .map(Foo::getProp)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you have Guava, you can get a transformed view of your list like this:

```
List<String> list = Lists.transform(fooList, Foo::getProp);
```

The Java 7 version:

```
List<String> list = Lists.transform(fooList, new Function<Foo, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Foo foo) {
        return foo.getProp();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need!!